# Can't beat the "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." error while trying to follow redux.js.org tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to follow the redux tutorial on redux.js.org. I stumbled upon this " "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions" error. It doesn't make sense because my actions are indeed plain objects (at least I think so), so I shouldn't be forced to use any middleware. (My attempts to use thunk also failed but this is not the concern of this question)

Here are my action creators:

```
export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'
export const TOGGLE_TODO = 'TOGGLE_TODO'
export const SET_FILTER = 'SET_FILTER'

export const VisibilityFilters = {
    SHOW_ALL: 'SHOW_ALL',
    SHOW_COMPLETED: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
    SHOW_ACTIVE: 'SHOW_ACTIVE'
  }

export function addTodo(todoText) {
    return 
    {
        type: ADD_TODO
        todoText
    }
}

export function toggleTodo(index) {
    return
    {
        type: TOGGLE_TODO
        index
    }
}

export function setFilter(filter) {
    return 
    {
        type: SET_FILTER
        filter
    }
}
```

My reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { 
    ADD_TODO,
    TOGGLE_TODO,
    SET_FILTER,
    VisibilityFilters 
} from '../actions'

const { SHOW_ALL } = VisibilityFilters

function todos(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
          return [
            ...state,
            {
              text: action.text,
              completed: false
            }
          ]
        case TOGGLE_TODO:
          return state.map((todo, index) => {
            if (index === action.index) {
              return Object.assign({}, todo, {
                completed: !todo.completed
              })
            }
            return todo
          })
        default:
          return state
        }
    }

function visibilityFilter(state=SHOW_ALL, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_FILTER:
            return action.filter
        default: 
            return state
    }
}

const todoApp = combineReducers({
    visibilityFilter,
    todos
  })

export default todoApp
```

...And finally the index.js (main):

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import todoApp from './reducers';
import {
    addTodo,
    toggleTodo,
    setFilter,
    VisibilityFilters
  } from './actions';


  const store = createStore(todoApp)

  // Log the initial state
  console.log(store.getState())
  // Every time the state changes, log it
  // Note that subscribe() returns a function for unregistering the listener
  const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
    console.log(store.getState())
  )
  // Dispatch some actions
  store.dispatch(addTodo('Learn about actions'))   // This line causes the error.
  store.dispatch(addTodo('Learn about reducers'))
  store.dispatch(addTodo('Learn about store'))
  store.dispatch(toggleTodo(0))
  store.dispatch(toggleTodo(1))
  store.dispatch(setFilter(VisibilityFilters.SHOW_COMPLETED))
  // Stop listening to state updates
  unsubscribe()
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I'd appreciate if you clear the cloud for me so that I can continue my Redux journey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the return object brakets in the same line

```
export function addTodo(todoText) {
    return {
        type: ADD_TODO
        todoText
    }
}
```

Comment: Really?? I can't believe this was the reason. And is there an article that explains the rational behind?

Comment: By default javascript put a semicolon at the end of the line, and your return statement will transform to
`return;
    {
        type: ADD_TODO
        todoText
    }`

Comment: You can see in more details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion